# Tableview reloads twice when dismiss SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two VCs. first one is a MealsVC that has tableview full of meals. And second one is DetailsVC ( meal details) . When users select a meal from tableview `DetailsVC` pops up and when user hits the X button `DetailsVC` gets dismissed. However, the meals get reload again and it creates double meals( 6 meals instead of 3 )

I found a solution somewhere but it doesn't work at all. Here is how I dismiss from `DetailsVC` to `MealsVC`( from the solution )

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    DataManager.shared.firstVC.tableView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and in 'MealsVC`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DataManager.shared.firstVC = self
```

and created `singleton`

```
import Foundation
 class DataManager {

static let shared = DataManager()
var firstVC = MealsVC()
 }
```

I also tried to perform Segue from `detailsVC` to `MealsVC` but the tableView isn't reloading, it displays an empty tableview

**UPDATE**

Get data in MealsVC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    getMeals()
}

  func  getMeals () {
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: para,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in


if let value : AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject {

let meals = JSON(value)

   // get meals code 

        let info = Meals(meal_id: id, Logo: logoString, meal_name: name, price: price)

        self.meals.append(info)

    }


    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

} else {

print("sorry data from api has some errors")
}

}

}
```

Comment: you can remove all your previous objects or use a flag for load only once

Comment: why are you reloading the tableView in the dismiss method?

Comment: @HarrySingh that's the solution I found and it's not working. even if I don't reload the table from dismiss the tableview have duplicated cells

Comment: can you show ur code relating to the tableView data source and where it gets updated.

Comment: @ReinierMelian it still reloads duplicated cells

Comment: @HarrySingh please check my updated question

Comment: `ViewWillAppear` is called twice that's why you have duplicate meals. `ViewWillAppear` is called when you first load the `viewController` and 2nd time when you dismiss the `DetailsVC`.

Comment: @leo0019 this is your real code or you modified for posting here, because there I think is missing something

Comment: You should move your `getMeals()` call to `viewDidLoad` so that's it's only called once. If you want to keep it where it is throw the call inside a dispatch once so that it's only called once. Another solution is instead of appending to `self.meals` just replace it all together.

Comment: thanks, solved it with @Harry's solution